# Получить последующие строки после Range Word C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Здравствуйте! Есть код, который ищет текст в Word'e и возвращает соответственно полностью объект Range(могу перебрать параграфы и вывести), но как дальше двигаться? Если я хочу вывеси после этого текста следующие строки, но мне дается возмоность управлять только одним абзацов, а как после него двинуться на следующий? Или как 'подсветить нужный диапазон' с найденного Range - дойти до конца, SetRange требует позиций, как их получить?

```
private Word.Range FindInWord()
    {
        object stringToFindObj = textBox1.Text;
        Word.Range wordRange;
        bool rangeFound;
        object _missingObj = Type.Missing;
        for (int i = 1; i <= doc.Sections.Count; i++)
        {
            wordRange = doc.Sections[i].Range;

            Word.Find wordFindObj = wordRange.Find;
            object[] wordFindParameters = { stringToFindObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj };

            rangeFound = (bool)wordFindObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wordFindObj, wordFindParameters);

            if (rangeFound) { return wordRange; }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем ясен вопрос, но как я понял метод должен быть примерно таким для ваших нужд:

```
private Word.Range FindInWord(out Section currentSection, out int index)
    {
        object stringToFindObj = textBox1.Text;
        Word.Range wordRange;
        bool rangeFound;
        object _missingObj = Type.Missing;
        for (int i = 1; i <= doc.Sections.Count; i++)
        {
            wordRange = doc.Sections[i].Range;

            Word.Find wordFindObj = wordRange.Find;
            object[] wordFindParameters = { stringToFindObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj, _missingObj };

            rangeFound = (bool)wordFindObj.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wordFindObj, wordFindParameters);

            if (rangeFound)
            {
                currentSection = doc.Sections[i]; 
                index = i;
                return wordRange; 
            }
        }
        currentSection = null;
        index = -1;
        return null;
    }
```

Код не проверял тк нет возможности сейчас и нужно не забыть обработать параметры после выполнения функции.